# X11 fonts are missing in solaris

Tags: x11, solaris

I run SlickEdit (IDE) on the Solaris 11 machine and on my windows I run X server (xming/xlaunch).
I dont see fonts in the GUI, i see small squares instead (as in picture below).

I suspect i am missing fonts at `/usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/`

What package should i download and where do i download it from ?

```
SunOS solaris11 5.11 11.0 i86pc i386 i86pc  
root@solaris11:~# cat /etc/*release  
                           Oracle Solaris 11 11/11 X86  
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  
  All rights reserved.  
                            Assembled 18 October 2011  
root@solaris11:~#
```

**update**: I have another solaris (5.10) that the UI does **work**, the fonts are working (and in their location), when i list X11 directory there i see the content:

```
-bash-3.00$ ls -la /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  15 root     bin          512 Mar  9  2008 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 root     bin         1024 Mar  9  2008 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         5120 Mar  9  2008 100dpi
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         5120 Mar  9  2008 75dpi
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     bin          512 Mar  9  2008 CSL
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         1024 Mar  9  2008 encodings
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     bin         2048 Mar  9  2008 F3
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         9216 Mar  9  2008 F3bitmaps
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         230 Mar  9  2008 fonts.cache-1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         2560 Mar  9  2008 misc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin          512 Mar  9  2008 Speedo
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     bin         3072 Mar  9  2008 TrueType
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         3072 Mar  9  2008 TTbitmaps
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     bin         1024 Mar  9  2008 Type1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin          512 Mar  9  2008 Type3
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     bin         2048 Mar  9  2008 Xt+
-bash-3.00$
```

this increases my suspicion something is invalid regarding to fonts.
[image]

Comment: X11 fonts should be installed on the X server (e.g. your Windows PC)

Comment: So what am i missing ? My windows is working fine with all other distros.. i do the same thing with linux and it works fine

Comment: I have no idea. Did you try to run some terminal emulator on the Solaris machine, then to start your SlickEdit in that terminal? Perhaps you'll see helpful error messages. BTW consider also switching to another editor (like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/))

Comment: i have existing machine solaris 5.10 that works - I will try to compare installed packages between machines.. to see what i am missing in the solaris 5.11

Comment: Play also with `xlsfonts` and compare the outputs on various machines.

Comment: xlsfonts is not found, when trying to install i get error Unable to contact any configured publishers.
This is likely a network configuration problem.
Framework error: code: 56 reason: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
URL: 'http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release - need to fix this///

Comment: On Solaris 11, `/usr/openwin` is a backwards compatibility relic - all fonts should actually be installed under `/usr/share/fonts`.  Applications using the traditional X11 font system require fonts be installed on the system running the X server (i.e. the machine with the monitor, mouse & keyboard attached) - those using the newer Xft system require fonts on the system running the applications (X clients).

Comment: thanks for informative response. I understand packages such as xorg-core fonts-core are missing and needs to be installed. When I list ls -la /usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/ - there are .enc files.. nothing else exists on /usr/share/fonts/X11 other that the encoding directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing packages: xorg-core, fonts-core

```
pkg install xorg-core fonts-core
```

Everything works fine.